# Physics Simulation - Setting Rigid Body World in the Code

Tags: python, physics

I have an issue on a physics simulation in Blender. I code a falling down cubes and texted on the code the rigid world properties like cache.

To be brief when a run the code it doesn't generate the cubes grid as I want and the simulation doesn't run, when I set manually the rigid world properties in Blender and comment the rigid world strings the code works correctly.

Maybe is a Blender bug but I'm not sure. Anyone has any idea?

```
import bpy
import random
import numpy as np
#======================================================
# Time simulation parameters
start_f = 0
end_f = 1000
mult_delay = 10
#======================================================
bpy.ops.rigidbody.world_add()
bpy.context.scene.frame_end = end_f
bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_start = start_f
bpy.context.scene.rigidbody_world.point_cache.frame_end = end_f
#======================================================
mass = 1000.
d = 0.999
f = 0.8

Dn    = 1       # Numerical diameter [m]

nrows    = 8    # Number of cube according to x axes
ncolumns = 5    # Number of cubes according to y axes
nLayer   = 2    # Number of vertical layer

a = 1.40        # Spacing between cubes according to x axes
b = 1.40        # Spacing between cubes according to y axes
c = 1.50        # Spacing between cubes according to z axes

# First element coordinate
x1 = -(Dn*nrows/2.+(nrows/2-1)*(a-1)*Dn)+(a-1)*Dn/2.0
y1 = -(Dn*ncolumns/2.+(ncolumns/2-1)*(b-1)*Dn)+(b-1)*Dn/2.0
DX = -2.*x1
DY = -2.*y1
z0 = 3
# Bottom slope
m = 0.15        # V/H

#======================================================
rectangles = [(x1, y1), (x1, y1+DY), (x1+DX, y1+DY), (x1+DX, y1)]
plane_mesh = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_plane_add()
plane = bpy.context.active_object
plane.location.xyz = (0,0,-x1*np.sin(np.arctan(m)))
plane.scale.xy = ((-x1+Dn/2.0)*1.1,(-y1+Dn/2.0)*1.1)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(   value=np.arctan(m), 
                            orient_axis='X', 
                            orient_type='GLOBAL', 
                            orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), 
                            orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', 
                            constraint_axis=(False, True, False), 
                            mirror=True, 
                            use_proportional_edit=False, 
                            proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
                            proportional_size=1, 
                            use_proportional_connected=False, 
                            use_proportional_projected=False, 
                            release_confirm=True)

bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()
# Assign the rigid body properties to the plane
rigid_body = plane.rigid_body
rigid_body.type = 'PASSIVE'
rigid_body.friction = f
#======================================================
cube_mesh = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
bpy.context.active_object.dimensions = (1,1,1)
#======================================================
bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='DESELECT') # Deselects all objects on the scene
cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']              # Create for cube
cube.select_set(True)                        # Selects only the cube
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = cube # Makes the cube an active object
#=====================================================

bpy.ops.rigidbody.object_add()               # Adds rigid body to cube

# Assign the rigid body properties to cube
rigid_body = cube.rigid_body
rigid_body.type = 'ACTIVE'
rigid_body.mass = mass
rigid_body.friction = f
rigid_body.linear_damping = d

zz = np.arange(z0,z0+c*Dn*nLayer,c*Dn)
xx = 0
yy = 0
cont = -1
for iz,z1 in enumerate(zz):    
    del xx,yy
    xx = np.arange(x1+float(iz % 2)*a*Dn/2., 
                   x1 + a*Dn*nrows    - float(iz % 2)*a*Dn,
                   a*Dn)
    yy = np.arange(y1+float(iz % 2)*b*Dn/2., 
                   y1 + b*Dn*ncolumns - float(iz % 2)*b*Dn,
                   b*Dn)

    data = []
    for x in xx:
        for y in yy:
            data.append([x,y,z1])

    print("data",data)
    lines = len(data)

    # for line in range(lines):
    #     pos = data[line]
    #     print ("pos",pos)
    for i, pos in enumerate(data):
        cont += 1
        delay = cont * mult_delay
        print('delay',delay)

        bpy.ops.object.duplicate()
        num1=random.uniform(0,2.0*np.pi) 
        num2=random.uniform(0,2.0*np.pi) 
        num3=random.uniform(0,2.0*np.pi)
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(   value=num1, 
                                    orient_axis='Z', 
                                    orient_type='GLOBAL', 
                                    orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), 
                                    orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', 
                                    constraint_axis=(False, False, True), 
                                    mirror=True, 
                                    use_proportional_edit=False, 
                                    proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
                                    proportional_size=1, 
                                    use_proportional_connected=False, 
                                    use_proportional_projected=False, 
                                    release_confirm=True)
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(   value=num2, 
                                    orient_axis='X', 
                                    orient_type='GLOBAL', 
                                    orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), 
                                    orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', 
                                    constraint_axis=(False, True, False), 
                                    mirror=True, 
                                    use_proportional_edit=False, 
                                    proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
                                    proportional_size=1, 
                                    use_proportional_connected=False, 
                                    use_proportional_projected=False, 
                                    release_confirm=True)
        bpy.ops.transform.rotate(   value=num3, 
                                    orient_axis='Y', 
                                    orient_type='GLOBAL', 
                                    orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), 
                                    orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', 
                                    constraint_axis=(True, False, False), 
                                    mirror=True, 
                                    use_proportional_edit=False, 
                                    proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', 
                                    proportional_size=1, 
                                    use_proportional_connected=False, 
                                    use_proportional_projected=False, 
                                    release_confirm=True)
        obj = bpy.context.active_object
        obj.location = pos

        obj.rigid_body.enabled = True
        obj.hide_viewport = False
        obj.rigid_body.mass = mass
        obj.rigid_body.linear_damping = d    

        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='hide_viewport', frame=start_f)
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='rigid_body.enabled', frame=start_f)
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='rigid_body.linear_damping', frame=start_f)
        
        obj.rigid_body.enabled = False
        obj.hide_viewport = False

        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path='hide_viewport', frame=start_f + delay)    
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rigid_body.enabled",frame=start_f + delay)

        obj.rigid_body.enabled = True
        obj.hide_viewport = False
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="hide_viewport",frame=start_f + delay + 10)
        obj.keyframe_insert(data_path="rigid_body.enabled",frame=start_f + delay + 10)

obj.select_set(False)

cube.select_set(True)   
bpy.ops.object.delete()
#======================================================
bpy.ops.screen.animation_play()     # To start animation
```

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't write in all caps in the title or body of any posts, it is the written equivalent of shouting, is [harder to read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Readability) and may be [considered rude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Computing). Please use the [edit] button below the post to change you text into regular case.

Comment: Also use proper code formatting for posting scripts and python code

Comment: Yes, sorry for the mistake @DuarteFarrajotaRamos

Comment: No problem @ValerioGianforte. But hey, the title is still waiting for you and wants to get fixed  ;-)